# How to see path of written text file?

Tags: java, android, io

i want to see path of "abc.txt" with a textView on my android application. How can i do this ?

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("abc.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE));
        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(out); 
bf.write("hello world");
bf.close();
```

Edit: Shaped like path; emulated/legancy/android/data/com.hayro.project1/files/abc.txt or another thing.

Comment: Based on your recent edit, it looks like you are running on an emulator and want to see the path of the file on the system that is running the emulator?  Assuming that the file even gets created on the system (I don't know), wouldn't you know where the root of that emulator system is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File f = new File("abc.txt");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("abc.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE));
    BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(out); 
bf.write("hello world");
bf.close();
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

I'm only using System.out as an example.  You would simply use `f.getAbsolutePath()` to get the path and then assign it to an appropriate variable.

Comment: Result: I/System.out﹕ /abc.txt
My expectation was more deeply information.

Comment: @hayroreis That's the answer.  I'm not sure what your comment is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @hayroreis There isn't more information.  That is the path of the file.  Your question was, "I want to see path of "abc.txt" with a textView on my android application. How can i do this ?"  That's how.  If there is something else you were looking for, you may want to re-word your question.

Comment: @hayoreis  I think I see what you are looking for.  I edited my question.